# Nested If else statements used in a WordPress template isn't working

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, while-loop, backend

I'm not sure what is wrong with the nested conditions below. The else block never seems to get executed even when the image variable is not set(hero image being absent). Please help me find the problem with it.

```
<?php
if ( is_singular() || is_page() ):
if( have_rows('hero') ): while( have_rows('hero') ): the_row();
if( have_rows('hero_-_background_options') ): while( have_rows('hero_-_background_options') ): the_row();
$image = get_sub_field('background_-_image');
if($image):
?>
.default-hero .col .hero-bkg {
    display:none;
}
<?php  endif; endwhile; endif; endwhile; else: ?>
.default-hero.relative.bg-grey-light {
  display: none;
}
<?php endif; endif; ?>
```

Comment: What does `have_rows()` do? Does it do what you mean? Is it ever `false`? Check the output (e.g. with [`var_dump()`](https://www.php.net/manual/function.var-dump.php)). If it is `false` probably your blocks are wrong. I strongly recommend to use better indention and new lines, e.g. inspired from [PHP Fig PSR-2](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) or anything else. In the end I also strongly recommend to use curly brackets over `end` statements even though this might be personal preference. I feel it's extremely hard to read anything from this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: else appeared to be at the wrong place.

```
<?php
if ( is_singular() || is_page() ):
if( have_rows('hero') ): while( have_rows('hero') ): the_row();
if( have_rows('hero_-_background_options') ): while( have_rows('hero_-_background_options') ): the_row();
$image = get_sub_field('background_-_image');
if($image):
?>
.default-hero .col .hero-bkg {
    display:none;
}
<?php else: ?>
.default-hero.relative.bg-grey-light {
  display: none;
}
<?php endif; endwhile; endif; endwhile; endif; endif; ?>
```